# Asking someone if he/she likes something

Tags: difference, phrase-request, question, interrogative

How exactly do you ask someone if he/she likes something (for example a dish, a movie, a book...)? My doubt concerns the two options:

> A. Gefällt es dir?
>
> B. Wie gefällt es dir?

The second one could, in my idea, be translated as “How do you like it?”. Is the meaning the same between the two?

Comment: Please note that the subject pronoun ("es") has to match what it refers to. I.e. it could also be "sie" or "er", depending on the genus and number of the corresponding noun. (Apologies if this was obvious)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference between those two questions is that the first is a [yes-no question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes%E2%80%93no_question) while the second actually asks for a full expression.

They are translated like this:

> A. Do you like it?
>
> B. How do you like it?

So, there really is the same difference in English. The first one might influence the asked person to give a positive, and also short, answer. On the other hand, the second question would request a more descriptive answer, triggered by the “how” (or “wie“ in German).

Answer (score 3):

I believe the first one asks simply `Do you like this?` a yes-or-no questions. Whereas the second question asks **how** it pleases you, asking for further explanation for example what part you like in particular or to what extent it pleases you.

> Gefällt dieses Lied dir? Ja
>
> Wie gefällt dieses Lied dir? Das Intro gefällt mir gar nicht.

Comment: "Wie gefällt dieses Lied dir?" müsste eher "Wie gefällt dir dieses Lied?" heißen.

Answer (score 3):

Bei Essen oder Getränken würde man "schmeckt es Dir?" oder "wie schmeckt Dir das Bier / die Pizza / ...?" fragen.

Allgemein kann man auch "wie findest Du x?" oder "was hältst Du von x?" fragen, wobei x ein Film, eine Band, ein Buch, etc sein kann.